# Adding Price Attributes

Tags: 8, theming, commerce

I am searching how to add price values to existing product attributes in Drupal Commerce 2.X

For Example: 
T-shirt price = $10.00

A product variation/color = Red = +$2.00

A product variation/size = Large = +$3.00


Choosing the Red would increase the price to = $12.00

And Choosing the Large would increase the price to = $15.00


Is there a way to accomplish this in Drupal 8?

In Drupal 7 there was a module called [Commerce Product Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_product_attributes) that allowed the Admin to add ADDITIONAL pricing after choosing an attribute to the already set pricing.

Ex. Set Price = $10.00 // Selecting a [Product Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_product_attributes) with a price value of $5 would then increase the total cost due at checkout to $15.00

Answer (score 0):

Seems now you know the answer :)

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_bulk/issues/3035971

Comment: Absolutely. Commerce Bulk was a complete life-saver. It took me about one full work day to input the LARGE amount of variations I needed. Without Commerce Bulk I think it would have literally taken a 2 weeks to a month to complete. I really thank you for this module.